# How to override description of default methods in loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to override **description** of builtin methods. It would be really handful for API consumers if we can describe each parameter.

For example, if we see post call of Application model, it has number of parameters but without its description:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "realm": "string",
  "name": "string",
  ...
}
```

It can be well understood if we can add the description to each parameter. Is there a way to describe all the parameters of model definition which would reflect in loopback explorer? I am using loopback 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution on this https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2353. You can override description of your builtin model method by:

```
let create = ModelName.sharedClass.findMethodByName('create');
create.description = 'Your new awesome description';
```